# MathML and Java

Tags: java, android, math, libraries, mathml

I've been doing some research for a mathematical Android related project I'd like to embark upon and I stumbled across for the first time MathML.

Does anyone know of any Java libraries which can do any (preferably all) of the following things?

1. Parse MathML
2. Output MathML by parsing standard mathematical notation
3. Render MathML (particularly important)
4. Do any other cool maths-ey things (like re-arrange equations in terms of different things)

Number 3 is probably the most important, and number 4 the least.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've used [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) for rendering MathML in my [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) project (Java symbolic math system - point 4 of your list).
JEuclid may be too slow (especially at startup) to render MathML on a mobile phone.

Other alternatives for rendering math expressions with TeX:

- [JMathTex](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/)
- [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/)
- [JLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/)

and for re-arranging equations or as general Java math libraries:

- [Mathrider (Yacas for Java)](http://mathrider.org/)
- [Jasymca - Symbolic Calculator for Mobile Devices](http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/%7Edersch/)
- [Java Algebra System](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/)
- [Hipparchus - library of lightweight, self-contained mathematics and statistics components](https://github.com/Hipparchus-Math/hipparchus)
- [The Apache Commons Mathematics Library](http://commons.apache.org/math/)

Calculator projects for Android:

- [Calculator N+](https://github.com/tranleduy2000/ncalc) (GNU public license)
- [Jasymca for Android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasymcaandroid/) (GNU public license)
- [Arity calculator for android](http://code.google.com/p/arity-calculator/) (Apache license)

Comment: JEuclid is dependent on java.awt.image.BufferedImage and will not work in android

Comment: JMathTex is dependent on javax.swing.Icon and will not work in android.

Comment: @Ozzy Do you mean that what JEuclid does is basically take a MathML expression, turn it into an image, and display it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The W3C MathML Implementations page (http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/mathml_software_cat_editors.html) has a few that mention Java-based tools... that might be a good place to start looking.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

JScience ([jscience.org](http://www.jscience.org/)) looks like it has some experimental support for MathML being introduced.

- [JScience MathML Java class
  hierarchy](http://jscience.org/experimental/javadoc/org/w3c/dom/mathml/package-tree.html)
- [JScience MathML Java
  package classes](http://jscience.org/experimental/javadoc/org/jscience/ml/mathml/package-summary.html)

I would like to say I am extremely impressed with the features the JScience author has chosen and proven able to support with his powerful Java library.

It is a pretty amazing piece of craftsmanship.  If you are doing any significant amount of sophisticated mathematics in your Java programs, or just want to create a utility to punt around with then you should take a look at this library.  It might even give you some ideas for things you never thought about doing before because they were "too hard".

There is an open source project named [MathEclipse](http://www.matheclipse.org/) that might interest you too.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this for your Point #3 above (rendering): http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/

It does a pretty nifty job taking MathML and creating a JPG, PNG, etc. It will also display the equations in a GUI (and I'm guessing you can look at the GUI code and incorporate that into your own project)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on having a browser that will render MathML, of course.

An alternative would be to try [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/), a JavaScript library that uses TeX to render equations.