# Java Math(s) Parsing API

Tags: java, math, parsing, libraries

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java), I was wondering if anyone knew of any *free* (as in beer, as in freedom would be nice but not essential) math(s) parsing libraries for Java. I found one called [Jep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) which used to be open-source (ie: written by the community), but now costs $300 upwards (is this even legal?).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: By "math parsing," do you mean "mathml parsing"?

Comment: No. That's what my previous question referred to. I mean: (x+2)^2+(y+2)^2=9

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal to charge for the use of one's software?

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg: seems a bit unethical if the community has made contributions and you're receiving exclusive payment for their work. P.S: I am also honoured to be in correspondence with the inventor of Wordle. I happen to know that The Times use it constantly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [math expression parser](http://code.google.com/p/symja/wiki/MathExpressionParser) from my [Symja](http://code.google.com/p/symja/) project.

Answer (score 3):

You may find my [math expression evaluator](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/MathEval) useful; it's completely free and it's tiny.

Answer (score 2):

i released an expression evaluator based on [Dijkstra's Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, under the terms of the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I may just be daft but isn’t the old, GPL’ed Jep still [available as open source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/)?

Comment: So it seems. Wasn't convinced it was complete, but I'll have another look. Thanks!