# How to parse a mathematical expression on operans and operators and solve it without using Regex?

Tags: java, parsing, math, mathematical-expressions

I have some mathematical expressions as Java Strings `(100 % 6)* 7 =` and `Sin(45) + log 100 – 3 ^ 5 =`. I want to parse these on operands and operators then solve them.

But I don't want to use Java Regular Expressions. What is the best solution?

Comment: It's not 'splitting', it's called 'scanning' (or 'tokenizing') and 'parsing'.

Comment: @EJP tahnk you, I just edited it

Comment: So you need a parsing technology that you can access from java. There are questions that already ask and answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792261/java-maths-parsing-api

Answer (score 1):

bison+yacc may be what you want, a LALR text parser.

Comment: I'd recommend two Java-based solutions: ANTLR or JavaCC.  The former is more modern and better supported today.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class aaa {



     public static void main(String []args){

        try {


        String xyz = "3*3+3";
        String kkk = "(100 % 6)* 7";

        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine se = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
        Object result1 = se.eval(xyz);
        Object result2 = se.eval(kkk);


        System.out.println("result1: "+result1);
        System.out.println("result2: "+result2);


        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: It using JavaScript engine but I want to process in JAVA and it cant calculate sin and log

Comment: Mere code is not an answer at SO. You have to explain.

Comment: This is Java code.  Rhino is built into Java.  I disagree with EJP - code is perfectly okay.  Do what you can.  You wouldn't chide Jon Skeet if he posted code.