# MathML expression simplify/evaluate API

Tags: mathml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MathML and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java)

Does anybody know of a Java based MathML evaluator API? Specifically, I amlooking for something that will take a MathML document, and evaluate theconstant sections.

Example: If the MathML document contained a section that has the MathML tagsfor the expression 2*3 + 4*5 (ie, 2∗3+4∗5 ),

I would like the API to return the full MathML but with the value of tagfor 26 in place of the above MathML.