# How to render mathematical equations in Android

Tags: android, html, latex, mathjax

We use MathJAX to render equations expressed via latex on the browsers. How do you do something similar on the Android platform, if you need to express all mathematical equations (e.g. fractions, algebraic equations, calculus, differential equations, trigonometry)

Comment: Doesn't JavaScript run in the Android browser?  Why not try MathJAX and see what you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MathML and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java)

Answer (score 2):

there is jlatexmath or jeuclid but i dont know if it works with android

you can also render a html page save it to the sdcard and then show it using the webview

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter already said, you can use MathJax. There's an open source example android app listed [on mathjax.org](http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/mathjax-in-use-applications/). For a discussion about it, see the [MathJax User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mathjax-users/6JANlr-pFIQ).

If you need to build a more complex editor, there are a growing number of those built on/with MathJax.

- [MathEditor](http://ubermeatshield.github.com/MathEditor/) (open source)
- [wysiwhat](http://wysiwhat.github.com/Aloha-Editor/) (open source, Aloha-based, not quite wysiwyg)
- [mathicando](http://www.mathicando.com/en/), a commmercial one

[disclaimer: I'm part of MathJax but not affiliated with any of the above.]

Comment: Hi Peter , I have used this link [http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498] to render math exp in my android app. But problem is that i have some padding above and below maths expressions loaded in webview. I want to make it look something like this [https://lh3.ggpht.com/ojqarVVu8b5jWkr8FOLZDu3QNfg8sJvHeIaCMQFvoYl6sb2Mp46qNAeRePhOmdQ5RA=h230]

Comment: Not sure this is helpful after all this time, but this is probably https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/681

Comment: Peter> Mathjax is only for webview? What about native android apps that do not use webview.

Comment: Yes, MathJax was designed for the DOM. In nodejs, jsdom would be enough but I don't know of any way to use nodejs or jsdom on Android.