# Rendering Mathematical Equations in Android

Tags: android, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render mathematical equations in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370542/how-to-render-mathematical-equations-in-android)

I am working on an android app which need to render mathematical equation. Most of the maths on the web is stores in the form of images which is not possible in Android because of different screen sizes. WebView in android doesn't understand MathML. MathJax comes with 16MB of font (image) files which makes application heavy. jMaths comes with 80MB font (image) files. All the other answers on stackoverflow are just hints. Can someone give a real implementation example of rendering mathematical equation on Android phone?

Comment: Are you searching for a ready to use Android library or do you consider also using c libraries with the NDK?

Comment: @Dyonisos if it is possible by android library well and good otherwise I am open to all other options

Comment: I think the best approach would be to use the OpenGL ES 1.0 API in android. See: `http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es10.html` for an example. Unfortunately I cannot provide a math related example.

Comment: MathML has been implemented in Webkit https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/MathML & http://www.webkit.org/blog/1366/announcing%E2%80%A6mathml. Webview of android is based on Webkit. If we can figure out how to implement latest changes in WebKit to Android WebView. This should work.

Comment: 5370542 is different, here we have very specific problem and it remains unresolved.

Comment: I agree with Merlin - there's no information here that isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Gaurav> What did you finally use?

Comment: @Jasper You can strip down MathJax to reasonable size and use it. Project was scrapped therefore I did not use any.

Comment: @Gaurav Thankyou. It's surprising that no one has solved this problem for native android apps yet!!