# math or LaTeX engine for Droid phones

Tags: android, latex, mathematical-typesetting

Are there math or LaTeX engines available for the Android phone? The flashcard app I like best (AnyMemo) doesn't seem to be able to integrate equations into the flashcards except as graphics, requiring a lot more work on the user's part, and I thought a third-party math typesetter would be a possibility.

---

(Edit 2011.04.24) **More detail**: From elsewhere, I've received the following remarks on some of the available options:

- JScience: Only a parser. It is not useful for generating images.
- jsmath: Does not display correctly in the Android browser.
- JEuclid: Depends on AWT which Android does not have.
- JMathTex: Depends on Swing, which Android does not have.
- snuggletex: Depends on JEuclid (see above).

Perhaps the S.O. readership can think of another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MathML and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java)

Comment: Maybe try [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/)?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks; the answers there are indeed suitable ones for this question. Is it the done thing for me to delete this post, or since the question is different is there something else I should do now?

Comment: @texmad: Oh, you can leave the question here if you like, AFAIK. It might hit on some search that the other question does not, and help people that way. If the MathML question does not completely answer your original question, you might pose a fresh question that delves more deeply into what you're seeking. And, someday, if you implement some solution, maybe you could post an answer to your own question pointing out what you eventually chose, and accept your own answer, again with an eye towards helping other developers with similar needs in the future.

Comment: @CommonsWare: The question should remain open. I'll edit the original post to make clear why.

Comment: @texmad Suggest keeping your eye on this: http://www.extex.org/documentation/faq.html
Not what you're looking for, but you may find some joy tinkering with this: http://webuser.hs-furtwangen.de/~dersch/jasymca3/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built on jsMath, [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.com) is a wonderful browser rendering engine for LaTeX, MathML and AsciiMath, which works fine in the native Android Browser, and also in Firefox for Android. Unfortunately, though, none of these technologies (except maybe AsciiMath) is fully supported at this time. For example, only [certain](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html) LaTeX commands are supported. You can also read the documentation on [MathML support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathml.html) and [AsciiMath support](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/asciimath.html).

If you're comfortable with the command line, you can also try

- [TeX Live for Android](http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/), although it has been reported to not work with some devices.
- [TeXPortal](http://lameandroidhero.bitbucket.org/?page=texportal_intro), another work in progress effort to port the complete TeX Live to Android.

So, there are alternatives and everything has its ups and downs. I just hope Google converts Android to a full Unix system, it'll make things much easier for everyone.

Comment: I have added an android wrapper for the same and code is available on github. See if it is helpful too. https://github.com/Nishant-Pathak/MathView

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to generate a PDF out of you LaTeX code I'd suggest the Android app VerbTeX which does exactly that. It uses the facilities available at [Online LaTeX Editor](http://www.verbosus.com) to generate the PDF

Answer (score 2):

See [TeXPortal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal) on Google Play for a usable app.

Comment: Links are Dead don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [TeXPortal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal). It can download missing package automatically and running

fast.