# Rendering LaTeX natively in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, latex

I'm looking to render LaTeX natively in a UILabel.

I understand that it's possible to achieve a similar effect by interspersing images with standard text, but I wonder whether it's possible to achieve this without rendering on my server and asking for those images.

I've happened across this [Android-related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820740/typesetting-math-functions-in-latex-to-render-in-android-application) question/answer, but I'm hoping there's an iOS-specific solution out there that I'm missing.