# Generate java code from MathMl

Tags: java, xml, mathml

I need a tool to parse [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) file and generate Java code represents this file, Do you know any tool do this processes partially or completely?

Comment: may be duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. MathML is a markup language, not a programming language as such so it is unclear what the generated Java code should do. Are you trying to parse and render MathML in Java?

Comment: thanks for your responses, I want to use it to send math expressions in XML between two agents, each agent will process this expression i.e. It will be part of java code not a complete program of course.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : [JMathTeX](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/)