# Is there a math jar/library out there for android/eclipse/java to use that would format math equations?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math

All I want is for my Calculus App to display simple things that require formatting. (x^2-5)/(x-4)^4 is so much uglier and complex than what can be done. I already use html but the only thing html is good for in my app so far has been to format x^2 or do integrals and format pi. I want to be able to format division equations better and I want to be able to display limits better if possible. I know there are a few other questions somewhat similar to this but I did not find a clear answer. There seemed to be a problem with each solution and I just want any one that would be able to work to display calculus problems. It does not even have to be all of them, just some would suffice. I basically just want to code those equations into a better looking mathematical format to display for the user neatly so they can work the problem out easier.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to post whole feature requirements to.

Comment: Consider MathML.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java