# How to write a Square root in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, math, android-studio, square-root

What's the best practice to make a square root function in android in text form (ex. Quadratic equation). Could I do it in HTML in my XML file possibly? Or would have have to do it under java

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to show the √ symbol in text, or perform a square root operation on a number?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to *display* a square root symbol (Hint: You might want to edit the question to make this clearer). You might want to also start reading [MathML and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java). Android can't do MathML (chrome doesn't support it, either).

Comment: I want to show it in text format. Say like the quadratic equation, that's something I'd like to write in text form in a stacked fraction.

Answer (score 3):

double squareRoot = Math.sqrt(100);

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("f(x) = ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c"));
```

Answer (score 0):

X<sup>2</sup>
\    "you can make new String for Example"

Comment: <string name="x_square">X<SUP>2</SUP></string>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).