# Conversion of MathML to something which I can put in TextView or WebView on receiving the MathML string inside HTML tags

Tags: android, mathml

I am receiving something like this from web services as a string:

```
<p><span class="equation">(x = {-b pm sqrt{b^2-4ac} over 2a})</span><span class="equation">(x = {-b pm sqrt{b^2-4ac} over 2a})</span></p></br>
```

which I want to show in TextView or WebView. It contains MathML which I want to be converted in proper form.

I have read on the web that MathML can be converted to image form & used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MathML and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java)

Comment: There is no MathML in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Android.text.Spanned** to render it in textView

```
Spanned htmlAsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(yourString);
textView.setText(htmlAsSpanned);
```

hope this help!