# Math in Android Studio how to insert mathematical expressions in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing a quiz and formulas app where I need to use math formulas, how to insert an equation or formula in xml or android studio?

so far I know how to transform any given formula into mathml code but I don't know how to implement that code with my textviews in xml

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML?

Comment: so how do I implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly input the equations in XML, there are two possible solutions to this.

1- you can use
[Mathjaxwebview](https://github.com/vinayakmestri/mathjaxWebView)

2- there's a library named [MathView](https://github.com/Nishant-Pathak/MathView)